# C Collect2 Multiple Definition Error

Tags: c, linker, definitions

I am writing a driver for FRAM for a robot, and all of a sudden I started getting this error:

```
C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\cciezvMm.o: In function `_FRAM_driver_setup':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_FRAM_driver_setup'
cmm/FRAM_driver.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\cciezvMm.o: In function `_FRAM_log_data':
(.text+0xf): multiple definition of `_FRAM_log_data'
cmm/FRAM_driver.o:(.text+0xf): first defined here
C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\cciezvMm.o: In function `_FRAM_read_data':
(.text+0x7a): multiple definition of `_FRAM_read_data'
cmm/FRAM_driver.o:(.text+0x7a): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Done. Build Failed!
```

I am not sure what brought this about, but I have not been able to find multiple definitions in my code. Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef FRAM_DRIVER_H_
#define FRAM_DRIVER_H_

#include "simpletools.h"

typedef struct FRAM_driver_type {
    i2c* busID;
} FRAM_driver_type;

void FRAM_driver_setup(FRAM_driver_type* ptr, int sclPin, int sdaPin,
    int sclDrive);

void FRAM_log_data(unsigned char* string, FRAM_driver_type* ptr);

void FRAM_read(FRAM_driver_type* ptr);
#endif
```

Here is the c file:

```
#include "FRAM_driver.h"

#define FRAM_DEFAULT_ADDR              (0x50)
#define FRAM_MAX_MEM_ADDRESS           (0x00)
#define FRAM_FIRST_MEM_ADDR            (0x01)
#define FRAM_ADDR_SIZE                 (  2 )
#define FRAM_DATA_SIZE                 (  1 )
#define INT_SIZE                       (  1 )

void FRAM_driver_setup(FRAM_driver_type* ptr, int sclPin, int sdaPin,
    int sclDrive){
    ptr->busID = i2c_newbus(sclPin, sdaPin, sclDrive);
}

void FRAM_log_data(unsigned char* data, FRAM_driver_type* ptr){
    // Create a static integer initialized to the first memory address of the
    // FRAM. It is 0x01 instead of 0x00 because 0x00 is going to be used to
    // store the last memory adress being used. Also, create the int data_Size
    // and set it equal to the length of the string plus one.
    //
    static int mem_Addr = FRAM_FIRST_MEM_ADDR;
    int data_Size = strlen(data) + 1;

    // Send the size of the data being sent to the next available memory
    // address. This allows the FRAM_read_data funtion to know what size of
    // data to read. Then increment up by one memory address.
    //
    i2c_out(ptr->busID, FRAM_DEFAULT_ADDR, mem_Addr, FRAM_ADDR_SIZE, data_Size,
        INT_SIZE);
    while(i2c_busy(ptr->busID, FRAM_DEFAULT_ADDR));
    mem_Addr += 0x01;

    // Write data to the next address when the FRAM is not busy, then increment
    // the memory address by one again.
    //
    i2c_out(ptr->busID, FRAM_DEFAULT_ADDR, mem_Addr, FRAM_ADDR_SIZE, data,
        data_Size);
    while(i2c_busy(ptr->busID, FRAM_DEFAULT_ADDR));
    mem_Addr += 0x01;

    // Write the last memory address used to the first memory address of the
    // FRAM. Then wait for the FRAM to not be busy.
    //
    i2c_out(ptr->busID, FRAM_DEFAULT_ADDR, FRAM_FIRST_MEM_ADDR, FRAM_ADDR_SIZE,
        mem_Addr, INT_SIZE);
    while(i2c_busy(ptr->busID, FRAM_DEFAULT_ADDR));
}

void FRAM_read_data(FRAM_driver_type* ptr){
    // Initialize unsigned characters to receive data from i2c_in.
    //
    unsigned char logged_Data = 1;
    unsigned char logged_Data_Size;
    unsigned char last_Memory_Address;

    // Get the last memory address written to from FRAM_MAX_MEM_ADDRESS and
    // store it in last_Memory_Address.
    //
    i2c_in(ptr->busID, FRAM_DEFAULT_ADDR, FRAM_MAX_MEM_ADDRESS, FRAM_ADDR_SIZE,
        &last_Memory_Address, INT_SIZE);
    while(i2c_busy(ptr->busID, FRAM_DEFAULT_ADDR));

    // Loop through all of the filled memory addresses in the FRAM and print
    // the logged data in each address.
    //
    for (int i = FRAM_FIRST_MEM_ADDR; i <= last_Memory_Address; i+=2){
        // Get the data_Size from the odd memory address and store it in
        // logged_Data_Size. Then wait until the FRAM isn't busy.
        //
        i2c_in(ptr->busID, i, FRAM_FIRST_MEM_ADDR,
            FRAM_ADDR_SIZE, &logged_Data_Size, INT_SIZE);
        while(i2c_busy(ptr->busID, FRAM_DEFAULT_ADDR));


        // Use logged_Data_Size to store the data to logged_Data and then print
        // the data. Wait until the FRAM isn't busy.
        //
        i2c_in(ptr->busID, i++, FRAM_FIRST_MEM_ADDR,
            FRAM_ADDR_SIZE, &logged_Data, logged_Data_Size);
        print("Log: %d \n", logged_Data);
        while(i2c_busy(ptr->busID, FRAM_DEFAULT_ADDR));
    }
}
```

Lastly, here is the testbench file:

```
#include "FRAM_driver.h"

#define FRAM_SCL_PIN 28
#define FRAM_SDA_PIN 29

static FRAM_driver_type fram_obj;

int main() {
  const unsigned char* data = 2;
  FRAM_driver_setup(&fram_obj, FRAM_SCL_PIN, FRAM_SDA_PIN, 0);
  FRAM_log_data(data , &fram_obj);
  FRAM_read_data(&fram_obj);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I am using simpleIDE and the simpletools library for a Propeller microcontroller.

Comment: It says that those symbols are defined in both `cciezvMm.o` and `cmm/FRAM_driver.o`. There's no information given on what those files are and why they are getting linked together so we can't help you any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleIDE was including a backup of a file that was not included in the project directories. Actually, I couldn't find it anywhere. It was as if it was creating the backup copy of the code I was working on and then storing it in a temporary location whenever I ran the code. The file was removed from the SimpleIDE project files and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

> `C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Temp\cciezvMm.o: In function '_FRAM_driver_setup:`
>   `(.text+0x0): multiple definition of '_FRAM_driver_setup'
>   cmm/FRAM_driver.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here`

This error means that your link line is referencing `FRAM_driver.c` twice, and looks something like this:

```
gcc ... cmm/FRAM_driver.o ... cmm/FRAM_driver.c ...
```

Don't do *that* -- it obviously can't work.